# PowerBi embedded Alerts & notifications

Tags: powerbi-embedded

We are an ISV who provides a custom web application to our clients in which we would like to embed PowerBI reports.   We love the feature in powerbi that allows powerbi users to setup customized alerts within a PowerBI dashboard.

Is there a way to tap into the alerting capability within PowerBI to provide that same feature to the users within our web application for the embedded report visuals?

Comment: Explain this further...